# How to transform conical curves to spherical curves

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Is there any way to convert this conical shaped curves to shperical shape?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more the result you want? For instance, do you want the band to be flatten on a sphere OR do you want it to stay vertical (the band width) but with spherical offset from bottom to top?

Comment: for now it looks in cone shape, but I want to mould it into shpere shape

Comment: Make sure that the origin of the cone is at the location where the center of the sphere should be. Then use a cast modifier (spherical) and adjust the 'factor' parameter

Comment: Thanks @lemon for the hint, I will do it will post a comment when needed the help... You are like tutor for me who teaches me without any fee :P  LOL!